# EC2 instance cloning and terminating automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminate, cloning

The EC2 instance I have created and which host my website keeps creating automatically other "Clones". I have noted that it is created one or two clones from my original instance and after some time the original is terminated.
Everything happens automatically and lot of times with an interval of 1 hour between one and another occurrence. Certainly this will also entail a higher cost in the total amount we pay for the service.

So, my question is: What is happening?

I will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you usign only ec2 instances? or you are usign elatick beanstalk to create this instances?
If you are using elastickbeanstalk to create the instances this service of AWS creates instances depending of the consumed resources this tool divide the trafic of the users in the existent instances created to prevent which instance fail.

if you are using elastic beanstalk you can disable this option easy.

first you need to access to eleastick beanstalk in your aws console home, when you access to this tool you need to find your application and do click in this.

then in your left side shown one menu whit the option configuration, you need to do click this option.

when you do click on the option, in the screen appear a grid whit  different options, you need to select the scaling option, you do click in the gear icon.

then appear a screen similar to this:[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBC93.png)

then you change the valuer of maximum instance count for 1

but if you are receiving too many visits or petitions on your application, your application will be fail

Comment: Thank you very much Brayan!
I thought it was an abnormal behavior!
I will check this issue more carefully, because my website cant fail :D

Answer (score 0):

if you aren't using elastick beanstalk then you configured an auto scaling group previously if it's the case then you can modify this on your ec2 panel in the left menu appear the option Auto Scaling ->autoscaling groups and do clic in it, then find your autoscaling configuration and edit the details to change the number of instances to be created.
[Autoscaling details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKG1Z.png)